# Facebook Pages Messaging Permission Issue: Standard vs. Advanced Access Levels

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm encountering an issue with Facebook where I'm trying to send messages to regular users, but I'm getting an error message stating that the "pages_messaging" permission is problematic. In my developer dashboard, I've configured the "pages_messaging" permission to be at the Standard access level. However, other developers have mentioned that it used to be possible to send messages to users with Standard access level permissions.

My question is whether using the Standard access level or Advanced access level permissions is currently affecting the result I'm getting from Facebook. How should I address this error?

Your assistance and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

actually facebook response:
{"error":{"message":"(#10) Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is reviewed and the app is live.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":2018028,"fbtrace_id":"AIMZrgGFOQ"}}

expected:
{RecipientId:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", MessageId:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}